# Авторизация через JWT для микросервисов

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

Правильно ли я понимаю, что правильно будет сделать Authentication Server, как отдельный микросервис, у которого будет два контроллера, один генерирует JWT-токен, а второй проверять валиден ли он, и все другие сервисы стучатся в этот сервис? И будет ли очень плохо, если Resource Server (Получение юзера, создание юзера, удаление юзера) будет находиться в том же сервисе, что и Authentication Server?

Comment: генерировать - да, но проверять токен на валидность может уже каждый сервис сам.

Comment: @tym32167 А это не нарушает DRY-принцип, получается каждый сервис будет содержать код, который декодит токен и проверяет секретное слово?

Comment: не совсем так. Есть сервер аутентификации, у него есть 2 ключа - один публичный, для кодировки, второй приватный - для декодинга. Есть ресурс сервер, он получает запрос с токеном, в токене есть данные и подпись (подпись это по сути закодированные данные). Ресурс сервер качает публиный ключ с сервера аутентификации (один раз, или там раз в день\час) и после для каждого токена - пробует его данные закодировать открытым ключем, если полученное значение совпадает со второй частью токена, то токен считается валидным. Это моё понимание, как оно работает.

Comment: @tym32167 согласен, один из способов. Но все же мы не избегаем проблемы повторения кода, у каждого микросервиса будет код, который валидирует токен, не лучше ли валилацию сделать прямо в auth-server'е?

Comment: не лучше, вы так просто заддосите ваш сервер актентификации, если на каждый  чих будете его вызывать. Проблемы повторения кода не будет, если завернете его в общую для сервисов библиотеку.

Comment: Код, который валидирует токен, будет у каждого микросервиса полюбому, вопрос только в том, как часто дергать сервис аутентфикации. Предсавьте, что юзер открывет страничку, и страничка использует 10 сервисов, чтобы отрисоваться. Каждый из сервисов делает ещё 10 запросов куда то. Вы получите 100 проверок токена, оно вам надо так дергать сервер аутенификации?

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, думаю достаточно узнал из ваших ответов, если сгруппируете все вместе, помечу как правильный, думаю хорошая информация для начинающих.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сервис аутентификации должен генерировать токен, но проверять токен на валидность может уже каждый сервис сам.

Есть сервер аутентификации, у него есть 2 ключа - один публичный, для кодировки, второй приватный - для декодинга (в случае хеширования приватного не будет). Есть ресурс сервер, он получает запрос с токеном, в токене есть данные и подпись (подпись это по сути закодированные данные или хеш).

Ресурс сервер качает публиный ключ с сервера аутентификации (один раз, или там раз в день\час) и после для каждого токена - пробует его данные закодировать открытым ключем, если полученное значение совпадает со второй частью токена, то токен считается валидным.

Это конечно упрощенное представление. Более детально, из чего состоит токен, можно почитать [тут](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: Публичный ключ используется для проверки подписи токена, а не для того чтобы его закодировать.

Comment: А что по вашему происходит при проверке подписи токена публичным ключом? Назначение публичного ключа - шифровать, то есть пейлоад токена шифруется и результат проверяется на соответствие подписи. По крайней мере я так понимаю процесс.

Comment: Хотя если подумать, то шифровать стоит приватным ключом,  а публичным расшифровывать и проверять результат с пейлоадом. В общем, мне лень гуглить, если найдёте rfc , добавьте ссылку в комменты.

Comment: Если говорить про криптографическую подпись токена (JWS), то публичный ключ используется для вычисления подписи на стороне отправителя, а приватный ключ для верификации этой подписи. Верификация выполняется сравнением хешей, полученного расшифрованием подписи и хешем который рассчитал получатель из header.payload. 
Если говорить про шифрование токена (JWT), то для ассиметричного алгоритма отправитель шифрует публичным ключом токен, а получатель приватным расшифровывает. Еще вы почему-то шифрование называете кодированием.

Comment: Что то все смешалось либо у меня, либо у вас. Приватный ключ для верификации? То есть без приватного ключа верифицировать нельзя токен? Всегда думал, что для верификации публичный ключ. Ну и про хеши, у вас почему то и шифрование и хеширование вместе, зачем шифровать хеш, если есть пейлоад, который можно сравнивать? Вы хоть приведите какой источник откуда инфа? Вы комментируете ответ 4 летней давности, я тему уже не так хорошо помню, потому спорить не буду, но какая то ссылочка на источник не помешает.

Comment: Результат шифрования хеша - это и есть подпись (JWS).
если подпись проходит верификацию закрытым ключом, то клиенту можно доверять. 
здесь всё подробно описано https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#overview-example-jws, это ссылка с https://jwt.io/libraries?language=Java

Каким образом можно верифицировать запрос на основании полученного payload? 
с чем его можно сравнить, чтобы доверять источнику?

Comment: Я себе в голове представлял это типа ssl,  где один ключ шифрует,  второй расшифровывает.  Но видимо тут чуть сложнее,  как я понял: сервер берет пейлоад,  считает хеш от него,  хеш шифрует приватным ключем.  Клиент расшифровывает хеш публичным ключем, после чего тоже пересчитывает хеш2 от пейлоада и сравнивает хеш и хеш2,  если совпало,  значит подпись верна.  Если это так, то пейлоада,  зашифрованного хеша и публичного ключа достаточно для верификации

Comment: Да, я тут тоже запутался в ключах и сделал ошибки в комментариях. В общем, для библиотеки io.jsonwebtoken получается следующее: для верификации подписи (JWS) используется метод .verifyWith(publicKey), т.е. подписывается токен приватным ключом и соответственно верифицируется публичным. Если же по сети передается шифрованный токен, то для расшифровки токена (JWE) используется метод .decryptWith(privateKey) , т.е. шифруется токен публичным ключом и соответственно расшифровывается приватным (тут уже получается все наоборот).
https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#constant-parsing-key

Comment: Класс, хорошо, что пришли к общему знаменателю 