# Как организовать кеширование между сервисами в разных датацентрах?

Tags: java, архитектура, кэширование, проектирование, микросервисы

Прошу меня строго не судить так как я дилетант в микросервисах да и не силен в построении архитектуры приложения в целом.

У меня три вопроса касаемо архитектуры:

1. Как организовать кэш между двумя датацентрами которая одна например находится в МСК а другая в СПБ, чтобы сервисы в обоих датацентрах стучались в общий кэш ? Если поставить Hazelcast между ДЦ то по моему мнению (поправьте пожалуйста если ошибаюсь) доступ в кэш будет не таким быстрым, время уйдет нас сеть. Или в каждом ДЦ сделать свой КЭШ а синхронизацию между ними сделать через очередь ?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Как организовать авторизацию в микросервисном приложении ?  Моя архитектура вызывает у меня некоторые сомнения. При авторизации в сервисе Authorization  я кладу в общий кэш(для всех сервисов) токен и объект сессии, и при запросе клиента через APIGetway, например в сервис заказов, внутри сервиса заказов для проверки аутентификации я беру токен клиента и смотрю есть ли в кеше объект сессии по данному токену.
   Если есть то беру сессию и делаю необходимые операции с сессией. Если нет то кидаю исключение. Что скажете по поводу такой организации авторизации и аутентификации в приложении между сервисами ? Если есть вариант получше то буду рад узнать как правильно это все делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Допускается ли взаимодействие между сервисами внтури системы ? То есть можно ли из одного сервиса вызывать другой или в идеале сервисы не должны знать друг о друге ? Я планировал все обращения к сервисам сдеалть через APIGetway то есть исключил возможность сервисам вызывать друг друга, но со временем понимаю что так не получится, тоесть возникла необходимость взаимодействии.  Если допустить то как лучше сделать: через REST или через mq+events ?

Comment: 1) есть много подходов. Вам точно надо синхронизировать эти БД? Вам точно нужен общий кеш? Реализация сильно зависит от ваших требований

Comment: 2) как то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1136583/179763

Comment: 3) API Gateway для запростов к вашей системе извне, то есть для клиентов. Там не должно быть ничего, что не надо клиентам. Для взаимодействия сервис-сервис есть разные подходы, от discovery service / service registry  до прямого обращения. Тут сложно что то советовать. Главное учтите, что у вас может быть несколько инстансов под один микросервис и в таком случае вам понадобится балансировщик нагрузки, вот к нему вам и придется обращаться.