# Как сделать синхронизацию?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Доброго времени суток.
Суть такая, есть клиенты (приложения Windows) и нужно сделать на них синхронизацию данных.
Пока есть идея такая:

1. SignalR для оповещения, что доступны новые данные;
2. RestAPI для CRUD'a;

Т.е. при каждом запросе на API, API будет говорить SignalR'y, что нужно оповестить клиентов о новых данных.

Скажите, что можно просто гонять все данные через SignalR, но, например, при первом подключении будет идти запрос на получение всех актуальных данных, а их может быть, например, 10000 (допустим данных о пользователях), SignalR может не вывезти такую нагрузку (сколько у него там ограничение, 32кб?), да и я не думаю, что это правильный путь.

На сколько это реально и правильно ли.
Главный вопрос - как сделать это правильно.
p.s. - нагрузка не большая, поэтому предполагаю, что SignalR и API будут в одном сервере.

Comment: Я бы использовал SignalR для передачи сообщения о новых данных, после чего клиенты сами должны вызывать нужный API для синхронизации.

Comment: @tym32167 То есть моя затея - нормальная? Как будет лучше, использовать отдельный сервер с SignalR и отдельный для API? Или можно всё в 1 закинуть? Как сделать "Холодный старт" для клиента? Реально ли отдать с API, например, 10МБ данных в JSON'e?

Comment: зачем отдавать 10мб в json, делайте отдачу постранично. Ну и 10мб это немного.

Comment: Серверы можете использовать как вам нравится (зависит от ваших требований), для клиентов разницы нет. Разве что аутентификацию дважды проходить.

Comment: Холодной старт имеет какую то специфику? Вы на клиенте должны сохранять время последней синхронизации, чтобы не пересылать всю бд, а только те данные, что были со временем последней синхронизации обновлены/добавлены

Comment: Да я примерно так и хотел, страницами отдавать, просто интересен вопрос был про большие данные через API. А возможно ли использовать один JWT токен для SIgnalR и API, если они будут раздельными?

Comment: По идее для вас не должно быть разницы, синхронизируется клиент просто каждые полчаса или по сигналу, апи для синхронизации тот же будет.

Comment: По поводу jwt - зависит от того, кто и как его выдал, ведь вам на сервере надо будет проверить его валидность.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда вопрос будет другой, как правильно сохранить данные у клиента и проверить их на сервере при подключении? Как мне на клиенте понять, что из базы удалили, например, 1 заказ?

Comment: Тут много способов. Во первых из бд заказ не удаляется, он помечается как удаленный. Вы можете все действия хранить в отдельной таблице с датой/временем и накатывать эти действия на клиента или вы можете хранить дату последнего изменения заказа в таблице заказов и по этой дате понимать, надо этот заказ синхронизировать или нет. Тут все полностью от вашей задачи зависит.

Comment: Хорошо, примерно понял, спасибо за ответы. Можете написать в ответы - помечу ответом)

Comment: @tym32167 А еще важный вопрос, есть ли какие-то инструменты, чтобы создать код для запросов к API? Или всё делать с нуля?

Comment: типа https://swagger.io/ ? тут можно и API и клиента сгенерировать.

Comment: Хотя код для запросов пишется на раз, там ничего нет сложного.

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы использовал SignalR для передачи сообщения о новых данных, после чего клиенты сами должны вызывать нужный API для синхронизации.

> Реально ли отдать с API, например, 10МБ данных в JSON'e?

зачем отдавать 10мб в json, делайте отдачу постранично. Ну и 10мб это немного.

> Как будет лучше, использовать отдельный сервер с SignalR и отдельный для API? Или можно всё в 1 закинуть?

Серверы можете использовать как вам нравится (зависит от ваших требований), для клиентов разницы нет. Разве что аутентификацию дважды проходить.

Вы на клиенте должны сохранять время последней синхронизации, чтобы не пересылать всю бд, а только те данные, что были со временем последней синхронизации обновлены/добавлены

По идее для вас не должно быть разницы, синхронизируется клиент просто каждые полчаса или по сигналу, апи для синхронизации тот же будет.

> А возможно ли использовать один JWT токен для SIgnalR и API, если они будут раздельными?

По поводу jwt - зависит от того, кто и как его выдал, ведь вам на сервере надо будет проверить его валидность.

> как правильно сохранить данные у клиента и проверить их на сервере при подключении? Как мне на клиенте понять, что из базы удалили, например, 1 заказ?

Тут много способов. Во первых из бд заказ не удаляется, он помечается как удаленный. Вы можете все действия хранить в отдельной таблице с датой/временем и накатывать эти действия на клиента или вы можете хранить дату последнего изменения заказа в таблице заказов и по этой дате понимать, надо этот заказ синхронизировать или нет. Тут все полностью от вашей задачи зависит.

Comment: Может еще подскажите где взять лучшие практики в использовании JWT? С примерами кода, как генерировать и всё прочее, буду очень благодарен

Comment: @LiptonDev типа [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1136583/179763) или [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852085/179763)?

Comment: Ну что-то типа такого, да, но еще есть вопрос как управлять этими токенами, нужно, например, отозвать токен или поменять права доступа к сервисам, то нужно как, делать в базе таблицу с токенами?

Comment: @LiptonDev ну есть разные варинты. Обычно у токена есть определенное время жизни (например, 1 час), после чего необходимо получить новый токен. В таком случае, если надо заблокировать пользователя, можно и не отзывать токен - он сам через час потеряет актуальность. Но вообще такой вопрос заслуживает быть заданным отдельно, я сам не спец по токенам и возможно сообщество вам подскажет и расскажет лучше меня.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо :)