# Выбор инструментария для системы оповещения в приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, signalr

Суть такова - есть wpf приложение с списками. В БД(SQL Server) есть таблицы с данными списков, а также таблица пользователей. Нужно разработать систему оповещений при изменении данных в списках (кто и какую строку в каком списке) + в дальнейшем расширение а-ля фильтрация событий по пользователям и тд. Подскажите какой инструментарии может это реализовать: SignalR(как я понял это больше для ASP.NET), WCF или еще что-нибудь есть? Пока что я запутался в выборе.

Comment: Какая часть системы должна получать оповещения?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko клиент

Comment: Вам точно оповещения нужны? Может будет проще, если клент, напрмер, каждые 10 минут будет опрашивать сервер за даными?

Comment: Клиент - это desktop-приложение на windows?

Comment: WPF это клиент, все, точка. Если вы его используете как сервер, то вы получаете "кастрированный" сервер, который будет не удобный и многого будет лишен. Если вам нужно оповещать клиентов, то вам нужен именно сервер, одна центральная точка, к которой все WPF клиенты будут подключаться и через него общаться, а что там будет, какая логика и технология, это уже вопрос ваших потребностей.

Comment: @tym32167 да, пользователь должен в режиме реального времени получить уведомление об сделанном другим пользователем изменении в списке

Comment: Есть бд у гугла с поддержкой оповещений - FireBase.

Comment: ну тогда все зависит от вашего бекенда. Вы можете полагаться на http сервер и SignalR, вы можете использовать WCF, вы можете интегрировать ваши притложения при помощи общей шины типа RabbitMQ или облачной типа Aws SNS. При этом вам все равно придется писать код ручной синзронищации, чтобы получать обновления при запуске приложения или при потере/восстановлении полключения.

Comment: [Как сделать синхронизацию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1197836/179763) похожий вопрос?

Comment: @tym32167 похоже на то, но не могу точно сказать, ибо абсолютно новая тема для меня. Поэтому и задал вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 Я и хотел изначально использовать SignalR, только не было понятно логика взаимодействия. Мне казалось, что SignalR должен обращаться напрямую к серверу БД.

Comment: В вашем вопросе мало деталей. Возможно вы даже требования не до конца продумали. Вот представим, что сервер прислал вам сообщение, что что то изменилось - какие данные это сообщение будет содержать? Что список А изменил элемент с индексом 0? А если будет 2 сообщения по одному и тому же индексу одновременно, вы как узнаете правду? Как сервер будет хранить консистентность если все клиенты одновременно поменяют одни и те же данные? Как вы это будете контролировать? Может, Вам нужна история исзменений и ее синхронизировать?

Comment: SignalR - это библиотека, чтобы ее использовать вам нужен веб сервер.

Comment: @tym32167 я еще ничего вообще не продумал, и тз у меня нет, хах. Просто сказали сделать систему оповещений для списков, чтобы, условно, человек из отдела кадров видел какие изменения и в каком списке сделал человек из экономистов и тп. Поэтому и не особо еще понял какая логика и последовательность работы.

Comment: @tym32167 огромное спасибо за консультации!