# Авторизация пользователя в Api Gateway

Tags: c#, .net-core, микросервисы

Я пытаюсь понять архитектуру микросервисов, и у меня есть вопрос о том, как правильно авторизовать пользователя в Api Gateway или проверить его существование, если у меня есть отдельный микросервис пользователей для регистрации, входа в систему и выпуска токенов. Допустим, у меня есть два микросервиса: юзер сервис для регистрации, входа в систему и получения токенов и сервис заказов. У них есть свои базы данных. Также есть Api Gateway, который сейчас просто делает перенаправление.

У меня есть предположения:

1. Для каждого запроса к шлюзу api делать отдельный запрос к юзер сервису и проверять там токен и роль пользователя, и только потом перенаправлять запрос в сервис заказа.
2. Предоставить шлюзу Api доступ к базе данных пользователей для проверки токена и пользователя, а затем перенаправить запрос в службу заказа.
3. Объединить Api Gateway и юзер сервис (думаю, это плохая идея).
   Или есть догадки получше?

Comment: [Авторизация через JWT для микросервисов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1136025/179763) ?

Comment: @tym32167, это конечно хорошо но есть одно но, логаут. При логауте токен удаляется с базы данных юзер сервиса, поэтому каждый запрос проверяет его на наличие в базе, но как это правильно реализовать в Api Gateway это уже проблема(

Comment: надо ли вообще хранить токен? Как вы запросы от Gateway перекидываете во внутренние сервисы? Они тоже токен проверяют? У вас есть оба такоена (аутенификации и продления)? Какое время жизни у токена? Если токен живет всего 5-10 минут, надо ли заботиться о логауте? Нельзя просто с клиента токен удалить и считать, что логаут выполнен?

Comment: Для этого и существует Api Gateway, он делает проверку за другие сервисы, после этого перенаправляет запросы, если токен не хранить в базе то как мы поймем что пользователь сделал логаут?

Comment: ApiGateway существует не для проверки юзера. ApiGateway - это точка входа для клиента в вашу систему. Она много чего может делать, в том числе просто перенаправлять траффик в нужный микросервис без каких либо проверок. Потому я и спросил, что у вас конкретно происходит. Я вам задал 7 вопросов, вы не ответили ни не один из них - в том числе про логаут. Например, я не вижу смысла что то делать на серверной стороне при логауте клиента.

Comment: Ок, смотрите, мы делаем запрос на логин, берем токен, делаем с ним логаут, как при последующих запросах сервер поймет что этот токен не валидный?

Comment: Зачем серверу это понимать? 1) Вы получаете токены авторизации и продления 2) Логаут на клиенте означает, что клиент затирает в памяти оба токена, токенов на клиенте больше нет, а значит использовать он их не может. 3) Через 5 минут токен авторизации сам протухнет.

Comment: Api gateway существует также и для проверки чтобы не делать проверку в каждом сервисе

Comment: Но можно использовать токен вручную, за эти 5 минут можно сделать много чего с токеном

Comment: Вы будете делать проверку в каждом сервисе, если у каждого сервиса будут свои разрешения для юзеров. То, что вы пишете (проверка юзера только в gateway), это просто один из вариантов, но не едиснственный.

Comment: Какие проблемы то с испольщованием токена? Если клиент скомпрометирован, то есть третья сторона знает токены, то он знает и логин/пароль. Если клиент сам зловред, то ему нет смысла делать логаут.

Comment: " Если клиент скомпрометирован, то есть третья сторона знает токены, то он знает и логин/пароль." почему это при знании токена он знает логин и пароль?)

Comment: потому что токен приезжает клиенту тем же транспортом, которым клиент отправляет логин пароль.

Comment: Но токен можно просто вытащить из запроса

Comment: Это конечно маловероятно но возможно)

Comment: Как и логин/пароль, верно? Если злоумашленник может видеть весь трафик между сервером и клиентом, то он видит все логины/пароль/токены. Для защиты от этого и прилоумали https

Comment: Это тоже верно)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 2):

Cтандартный способ решения проблемы "как не лезть в базу" - использование двух токенов ([как в oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/)) - access token + refresh token.

Выделяете авторизационный сервис. Он должен в обмен на username / password выдавать два токена

Access Token - подписанный json (JWT), короткоживущий (минут 10), со вшитым временем действия. Он передается на каждом запросе.
Для его проверки не нужно лезть в базу, достаточно провеки подписи и времени действия. Готовые API Gateway ([Ocelot](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot), [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/)) умеют проверять JWT, доставать из него атрибуты (id пользователя, роль, флаги доступа к определенным фичам, что угодно) и прокидывать их параметрами в микросервисы.

Refresh Token - хранится на стороне клиента, и на стороне авторизационного сервиса (в базе). При истечении Access Token (или близко к истичению) клиент может полезть с refresh token в авторизационный сервис и получить новый Access Token.

Вылогинивание пользователя в этой схеме - это удаление Refresh Token из базы авторизационного сервиса. Клиент просто не сможет получить новый Access Token. Время жизни Access Token подбирается под конкретные условия. Если это защита от кражи девайса - до минут 15 достаточно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)