# Security на микросервисах quarkus

Tags: безопасность, микросервисы, quarkus

Допустим есть несколько микросервисов, один сервис будет маршрутизатором, как организовать допуск только аутентифицированным пользователям через сервис-маршрутизатор к другим сервисам, а прямой доступ к сервисам закрыть?

Примеров в интернете не так много, ещё и 90% англоязычные, тут на русском еле понимаешь...

В общих словах, прошу подскажите как должна выглядеть архитектура такого приложения?

Comment: Не работал с quarkus, но в Spring авторизацию между микросервисами обычно делают через [JWT токен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1136025/Авторизация-через-jwt-для-микросервисов).